# O caractere ' ' (ESPAÇO), conta na string na linguagem C?

Tags: c, array, string

Por exemplo, Só vai guardar no array as primeira letras antes do espaço, porque ? 
Alguém sabe explicar ai ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){     
    char nome[20];
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");    
    scanf("%s", nome);

    for(int c=0; c<20; c++{
        printf("%c", nome[c]);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Em C, o espaço é um caractere normal, como qualquer outro.

O que você está vendo de estranho aí, é que de fato a função `scanf` usa o espaço como um separador de valores de entrada por padrão.

Se você ao invés de `scanf` usar a função `fgets`, terá menos surpresas: todos os caracteres digitados pelo usuário serão transferidos para o vetor determinado por você  até uma quebra de linha (sequência de caracteres que depende do sistema operacional).

Além disso, o fgets, assim como scanf, adiciona um caractere `\x00`, que representa o final da string para a maioria das funções em C.

Em vez de:

```
scanf("%s", nome);
```

Sua linha de leitura ficaria assim:

```
fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
```

e você não teria surpresa com espaços, que seriam um caractere normal. Além disso, fgets pode ser usada em programas e bibliotecas de sistemas reais, que vão pra produção, por que tem o tamanho máximo da string a ser lida, e assim evita problemas de estouro de buffer.O scanf é uma função bem versátil para ler um número arbitrário de tokens, e até tipos de dados diferentes, mas é mais difícil de usar corretamente para casos simples.

Answer (score 0):

A função responsável pela captura ou leitura **scanf()**, sempre que você usar **%s** ele vai pegar a sequência de carácteres até ser adicionado um espaço vazio, que é representado por **'\0'** o final da sua sequência de caracteres("Null-terminated").

Então a string representa uma sequência de carácteres. Esta é a resposta mais simples a ser considerada.

Uma resposta mais completa neste link:

https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/string.html

*Referência: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/*

Comment: É então eu estava querendo adicionar '\0'  na mão e não estava funcionando kkk

Comment: Espero ter ajudado

Comment: O espaço  no seu array '\20' , 'x20'

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
gets (nome);
```

Que tbm dá certo